# SQL query MATCH with alias and order by and optimize query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, query-optimization, match

i'm using this query to search inside table:

```
SELECT 
   *,
   MATCH(tags,title,description) 
      AGAINST ('hey you are you in' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
FROM table  
ORDER BY insert_datetime DESC, id DESC
```

what i need is to use the alias 'score' to order results, is this the right sintax?:

```
SELECT 
   *,
   MATCH(tags,title,description) 
     AGAINST ('hey you are you in' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
FROM table  
ORDER BY score DESC, insert_datetime DESC, id DESC
```

is also there anyway to optimize this query ? better way to write that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > is this the right sintax?

   Yes.  As documented under [`SELECT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html):

   > A ***`select_expr`*** can be given an alias using **`AS alias_name`**. The alias is used as the expression's column name and can be used in **`GROUP BY`**, **`ORDER BY`**, or **`HAVING`** clauses.
2. > is also there anyway to optimize this query ? better way to write that?

   If you don't need the relevance score in your resultset, you need not select it:

   ```
   SELECT   *
   FROM     table  
   ORDER BY MATCH(tags, title, description) AGAINST (
              'hey you are you in' IN BOOLEAN MODE
            ) DESC, insert_datetime DESC, id DESC
   ```

   But sadly, as suggested under [`ORDER BY` Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/order-by-optimization.html), there is no way that MySQL can avoid undertaking a filesort when ordering by the result of a function such as `MATCH() ... AGAINST()`:

   > In some cases, MySQL can use an index to satisfy an **`ORDER BY`** clause without doing any extra sorting.
   >
   > The index can also be used even if the **`ORDER BY`** does not match the index exactly, as long as all of the unused portions of the index and all the extra **`ORDER BY`** columns are constants in the **`WHERE`** clause.

   However, one could:

   - filter the resultset for only those records of interest by using a `WHERE` clause, thereby reducing the number of results that must be sorted; and/or
   - reduce the maximum number of comparisons each sorting step will need to perform by removing unneeded columns from the `ORDER BY` clause.